# disable loading images in selenium firefox after creating the driver object with images enabled

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, firefox

I need to navigate between 5 pages with selenium in firefox. The first two pages should contain images but for the rest of them there is no need to load images. Is there any way to disable rendering images after I created the driver?
I found several posts with the following code which help you make the images disabled before building the driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver

firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so', 'false')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
driver.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com/')

driver.close()
```

But this disables the code before building the driver? Is there any way that I can do the same thing after I loaded some pages with images enabled?

Any help would be appreciated,